# C++ binary fork certain number in UNIX

Tags: c++, unix, fork

I am learning how fork works with Unix-like operating systems.
I want to create exactly 9 child processes with each parent can only create 2 children.
So this is a binary fork algorithm.

However I can't manage to limit the correct number of children to create in third recursion call.

Here is the flow of creating children.
[image]

Here is the code I have right now.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

static int CHILD_SIZE = 9;
static int LEVEL = 1;
static int MAX_LEVEL = 3;

void createChildren(int remaining, int level) {

    int CURRENT_REMAINING = remaining;
    
    if(CURRENT_REMAINING <= 0 || level > MAX_LEVEL){
        return;
    }
    
    pid_t firstChild,secondChild;
    
    // Fork the first child
    firstChild = fork();
    
    if(firstChild == -1){
        cerr << "Fork failed!" << endl;
    }
    else if (firstChild == 0 && CURRENT_REMAINING > 1)
    {
        // first child
        cout << "First child process (PID: " << getpid() << ") with parent process (PID: " << getppid() << ") at level: " << level << endl;
        
        // calculate how many child needs after this iteration
        CURRENT_REMAINING -= (2 * level);
        if(CURRENT_REMAINING < 0){
            CURRENT_REMAINING = 0;
        }
    
    }
    else if (firstChild > 0 && CURRENT_REMAINING > 1)
    {
        // Fork the second child
        secondChild = fork();
    
        if(firstChild == -1){
            cerr << "Fork failed!" << endl;
        }
        else if (secondChild == 0) {
            // second child
            waitpid(firstChild, NULL, 0);
            cout << "Second child process (PID: " << getpid() << ") with parent process (PID: " << getppid() << ") at level: " << level << endl;
    
            // calculate how many child needs after this iteration
            CURRENT_REMAINING -= (2 * level);
            if(CURRENT_REMAINING < 0){
                CURRENT_REMAINING = 0;
            }
        } else if (secondChild > 0){
            // Wait for both child processes to complete
            waitpid(firstChild, NULL, 0);
            waitpid(secondChild, NULL, 0);
        }
    }
    
    
    //---------- recursion call-----------//
    
    //  upper child recursion call
    if(firstChild == 0){
    
        cout << "current remaining in first child is: " << CURRENT_REMAINING << " at level " << level << endl;
    
        createChildren(CURRENT_REMAINING, level + 1);
    }
    
    // lower child recursion call
    if(secondChild == 0){
    
        cout << "current remaining in second child is: " << CURRENT_REMAINING << " at level " << level << endl;
    
        if(CURRENT_REMAINING > 3){
            //cout << "Create two more processes" << endl;
            createChildren(CURRENT_REMAINING, level + 1);
        }
    }

}

int main() {

    std::cout << "Parent process " << getpid() << std::endl;
    createChildren(CHILD_SIZE, LEVEL);
    
    return 0;

}
```

Here is the output:

```
Parent process 8571
First child process (PID: 8573) with parent process (PID: 8571) at level: 1
current remaining in first child is: 7 at level 1
Second child process (PID: 8574) with parent process (PID: 8571) at level: 1
current remaining in second child is: 7 at level 1
First child process (PID: 8575) with parent process (PID: 8573) at level: 2
current remaining in first child is: 3 at level 2
First child process (PID: 8576) with parent process (PID: 8574) at level: 2
current remaining in first child is: 3 at level 2
Second child process (PID: 8577) with parent process (PID: 8573) at level: 2
current remaining in second child is: 3 at level 2
Second child process (PID: 8578) with parent process (PID: 8574) at level: 2
current remaining in second child is: 3 at level 2
First child process (PID: 8579) with parent process (PID: 8575) at level: 3
current remaining in first child is: 0 at level 3
Second child process (PID: 8581) with parent process (PID: 8575) at level: 3
current remaining in second child is: 0 at level 3
First child process (PID: 8580) with parent process (PID: 8576) at level: 3
current remaining in first child is: 0 at level 3
Second child process (PID: 8582) with parent process (PID: 8576) at level: 3
current remaining in second child is: 0 at level 3
```

the first call makes 2 children
the second call makes 4 children
and the third call makes 4, but should be 3 instead.

Comment: What is your question? Also, it helps to extract a [mcve], often you find the error yourself. BTW: If you use any learning resource that teaches the use of `<iostream.h>`, that resource is outdated by more than twenty years! Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list for some better resources.

Comment: that diagram looks confused. fork() doesn't create two children, it creates a single child - a copy of original, second process is the original

Comment: The numbering in your diagram doesn't correspond to anything in your code - it'll be much easier to think about if you fix that first. I'd be tempted to recursively halve the _interval_ `0..9`, because then the number of children takes care of itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want each process to `fork()` at most twice, so you shouldn’t need any loops, recursion or some such.

Given a command line argument `9`, the following program [will print](https://godbolt.org/z/afde5ajbM) 10 times `Terminating.` and 9 times `Waited for: <pid>`, which seems to be what your drawing specifies.

```cpp
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

namespace {
struct Process {
  Process() : pid{fork()} { if (pid == -1) throw -1; }
  bool is_child() const { return pid == 0; }
  void disarm() { pid = 0; }
  ~Process() { if (pid)
    std::cout << (std::stringstream{}
              << "Waited for: " << waitpid(pid, nullptr, 0) << '\n') .str(); }
 private:
  pid_t pid;
};
struct Blah { ~Blah() { std::cout << "Terminating.\n"; } };
}  // namespace

int main(int argc, const char *const argv[]) {
  Blah blah;
  if (argc != 2) return EXIT_FAILURE;
  size_t remaining;
  if (!(std::stringstream{argv[1]} >> remaining)) return EXIT_FAILURE;
fork_again:
  const size_t old_remaining{remaining};
  remaining = old_remaining / 2 + old_remaining % 2;
  if (!remaining) return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  Process firstFork;
  if (firstFork.is_child()) {
    if (--remaining) goto fork_again; else return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  }
  remaining = old_remaining - remaining;
  if (!remaining) return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  const Process secondFork;
  if (secondFork.is_child()) {
    firstFork.disarm();
    if (--remaining) goto fork_again;
  }
}
```

With just the two unconstrained `fork()`s, it would be an equivalent of this Bash awesomeness:

```bash
_()(_&_&);_
```

To tame the exponential growth in the number of processes, we limit the number of times a process can `fork()` as we proceed up the `fork()`ing tree, and that number needs to decrease exponentially if we want a constant total number of `fork()`s.

The rest is all about getting the details (somewhat) right. The first subtree is granted `remaining / 2 + remaining % 2` of `fork()`s, the second subtree gets the rest. This handles both odd and even cases correctly. Additionally, all processes other than the original (grand)parent must count *themselves* too, which is why they always start with `--remaining`.

The use of RAII in this code is controversial when it comes to readability, due to [the `goto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/goto). I’m almost sure there is a way to implement it without a backward-jumping `goto` statement, but I’m also way too lazy to figure this out.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I succeeded in implementing the program. Now I understand the flow of creation child process